# Does iOS have the capability to execute multiple apps in memory, and enable you to switch between them, restoring the previous state?

Tags: ios, memory, kernel, multitasking

This is for buying purposes; i.e. does the kernel schedule the processes and threads belonging to every process, and do the apps save states that can be resumed at the user's discretion?

Please fill me in on the scheduling/structure of iOS's kernel.

Comment: What are you asking do you want to ask does the user sea multitasking or how does the kernel work?

Comment: Whatever you believe is the answer.

Comment: It depends on the question

Comment: The question is right above. The answer is fine regardless of it being more about the kernel or user apps.

Comment: The issue is that the answers differ.

Comment: @Mark Maybe you can provide them both?

Comment: Stack exchange is designed for questions that have one answer

Comment: The "buying" answer is that yes, the system can keep multiple applications in memory and supports "save" or restore states. (Whether applications take advantage of that is another story.) Some limited background processes are possible but are tightly controlled by the APIs that Apple chooses to make public. They mostly center around playing audio and GPS/location updating.

Comment: There are two questions here and an answer to one has no bearing to the other. Feel free to ask the parallel question on how multitasking works. Once you have a good understanding of both how suspend / resume works and multithreading works - should you have a question about synthesizing both issues into a practical question - feel free to ask that too at a later date.

Answer (score 1):

No - the multithreading of processes is reserved for Apple OS only and apps (including almost all Apple apps) do not get to execute simultaneously when they are not in the foreground drawing to the iOS screen. Only if the app calls some limited API (safari or other webkit apps downloading in the background is one of the white listed background tasks - FWIW) can the app get work done on it's behalf by the OS/kernel when the app itself is in a suspended state.

The iOS kernel is the same foundation as the OS X kernel, so your question about app suspend / resume state is more about the application frameworks in use than the underlying structure of the kernel.

That being said, the iOS idiom is to have apps paused by the OS at any time and various states are cached and saved so that once the kernel resumes execution of an app - whether it was paused for a few dozen milliseconds or a few hours is seamless to the user when the app is programmed correctly.

Of course, not all apps adhere to this idiom, but most do.